# How to write a linearly "decaying" equation?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, combinations, linear-programming

I have a system that runs detectors. Each detector runs its query at some frequency, we get back datapoints and then do threshold evaluation on those datapoints.

Some detectors queries have high granularity queries (eg: 60s), while others have much worse (eg: 2 hours)

So for high granularity detectors, I want to run them more often because the chances of getting new datapoints is much higher as they are highly granular

So I'm trying to write a function that, given the granularity of detector query, can figure out how often to run it.

So basically, the more granular the query is, the more often I want to run it. It's a linear relationship.

I was thinking of this: `frequency = k *query_granularity`, where k  <=1

That kinda makes sense. If k = 0.5, then I'm going to run a 60s detector a lot more often than I'm gonna run a 1hour detector. (ie: I'll run the 60s query detector every 30s, whreas I'd run the 1hour detector only every 30mins)

The problem is: I want the factor to be a *decaying* constant, not a linear one.

I don't want a detector with a query granularity of 5 hr to have a frequency 5x lower than a 1hr detector.

Can someone help me formulate a way to frame this?

Comment: Instead, you want the 5hr one to have a frequency 25x lower? Or 7.5x? Give us an idea where you aim at. The field of options is very broad.